# PHP Call to undefined method

Tags: php, sql

estoy tratando de hacer el select con los datos de una columna de mi tabla de SQL... La consulta me funciona por que la utilizo para otro lado de la pagina, pero no puedo hacer andar a la funcion que me retorna ese arreglo y me tira el siguiente error:

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method GamesView::getALLGeneros() in C:\xampp\htdocs\trabajo-practico-especial\templates\form_alta.php:17 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\trabajo-practico-especial\app\views\games.view.php(9): include() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\trabajo-practico-especial\app\controllers\games.controller.php(24): GamesView->showGames(Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\trabajo-practico-especial\router.php(20): GamesController->Show() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\trabajo-practico-especial\templates\form_alta.php on line 17**

Les dejo el codigo para que puedan verlo:

Este es mi formulario:

```
 <div class="col-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Genero</label>
                
              <?php
              $GamesController = new GamesController();

              $GamesController->getALLGeneros();?>
                
                <select name="Genero" class="form-control">
                    <?php foreach ($GenerosAMostrar as $g) { ?> 
                    <option value="<?php echo $g?>"><?php echo $g ?></option>
                    <?php  } ?>
                </select>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

Model de consultas: 

public function getALLGeneros(){
$query = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * from generos');
$query->execute();
$generos=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


return $generos;
 }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea 17 de form_alta.php?

Comment: Hola gracias por responder.               <?php $GenerosAMostrar = $this->getALLGeneros();?>

Comment: ¿En cuál archivo está `getALLGeneros()`? ¿Es una clase?

Comment: Lo tengo en un archivo games.model.php que es una clase y ademas es donde hago todas las consultas a la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Tu `form` está en la misma clase que contiene a `getALLGeneros()` o en una clase que extienda de ella? Parecería que sí, porque estás usando `$this` en la llamada, pero por el mensaje de error parece que no. Supongo que en ese contexto tienes una instancia de la clase que posee al método y deberías hacer la llamada así: `$laInstancia->getALLGeneros();` Es un aspecto fundamental para resolver el problema que planteas, pero no explicas nada al respecto.

Comment: Mi form esta en un archivo php solo, que después se integra en una funcion que muestra el form y un par de datos mas en templates/games.view.php que es donde tengo guardada toda la interfaz que ve el usuario... Instancie y lo llame de esa forma (que es la misma que cuando hago el ruteo y llamo una funcion) pero no tuve resultado, me sigue el mismo error.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás instanciando? no lo veo en el código que nos compartes.

Comment: Ahi te deje el codigo editado para que veas si lo instancie bien.. gracias por la paciencia.